# MSSQL Query with Variables are very slow

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have a big performance Problem with my Query: I use Java Spring boot 3.1.1 with JDBCTemplate.

My Program executes this Query on MSSQL Server:

```sql
    DECLARE @P0 Integer; 
    DECLARE @P1 Integer; 
    DECLARE @P2 Integer;
    
    SET @P0 = 1476;
    SET @P1 = 1476;
    SET @P2 = 1476;
    
    select 
        *
    from 
        SL.dbo.t024 WITH (READPAST) 
        JOIN SL.dbo.t023 WITH (READPAST) ON t024.c011 = t023.c010
        JOIN SL.dbo.t346 WITH (READPAST) ON t023.c004 = t346.c002
    where 
        t024.mesoyear = @P0 
        AND t023.mesoyear = @P1 
        AND t346.mesoyear = @P2 
        AND (t024.c014 = 1 OR t024.c014 = 0)
        AND (t024.c038 IS NULL OR t346.c002 <> '999')
    Order BY
        t346.c002,
        t024.c002
```

It takes 8 seconds to finish! BUT when i change the Statement (in MSSQL Studio) to:

```sql
    select 
        *
    from 
        SL.dbo.t024 WITH (READPAST) 
        JOIN SL.dbo.t023 WITH (READPAST) ON t024.c011 = t023.c010
        JOIN SL.dbo.t346 WITH (READPAST) ON t023.c004 = t346.c002
    where 
        t024.mesoyear = 1476 
        AND t023.mesoyear = 1476 
        AND t346.mesoyear = 1476 
        AND (t024.c014 = 1 OR t024.c014 = 0)
        AND (t024.c038 IS NULL OR t346.c002 <> '999')
    Order BY
        t346.c002,
        t024.c002
```

then it takes 0 seconds to finish!

on the first Satement with Variables the MSSQL Studio Execution plan says that he didn't find the indexes, bu on the second statement he find the indexes and it is very fast! WHY??

The next one i find is that when i add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of the first Query with Variable so the Query finishes in 0 seconds.

So what's the problem here? How can i solve this? i cannot test every query for `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is needed!

the same could happen also with JPA and Hibernate... I dont know where the issue is! OR how i can solve this without `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Comment: Seems like a plan has been cached for the variables query which isn't useful (any more). This could possibly be due to parameter sniffing, where a prior run for the values passed made that query plan make more sense.

Comment: As a side note, I very much doubt you want/need `SELECT *`, and should be specific on the columns you need. Why do you need both `t024.c011` and `t023.c010` returned, for example, when you know they'll have the same value? Limiting the columns could well provide a benefit when you can use a less wide, and also now covering, index.

Comment: I expect adding an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint will address the issue. TL;DR: see [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Comment: If you're on the newest version of SQL Server (2022 at time of writing), have query store enabled, and have good indexing and up to date statistics, SQL Server may also be clever enough to cache multiple plans for your query for the different parameter values, as it'll recognise the different needs. We don't know enough about the query, or your environment, to know it that might occur though.

Comment: So i understand what the problem is BUT i dont understand WHY this problem appears! P0 and P1 and @P2 are integers AND mesoyear are also an integer and are indexed. so why mssql should use a diffenrent Executionplan? sorry but i dont understand the problem here. and this also doesnt have Subquerys it only has 2 Joins. so WHAT could be different for SQL when i say mesoyear = P0 (both are integer!)

Comment: If everything else fails, you can rewrite it to dynamic sql which concats the parameters (ie. non-parametrized query). Of course you need to think of injection etc but if your parameters are integer's it's not a problem.

Comment: @Sametcey because sql server doesn't know the parameter values if it's hidden in a variable. consider code that does: `declare @a int; set @a = 5; if 1 = 0 SET @a = 2; SELECT * FROM sometable where ID = @a` Here, it cannot pinpoint @a to exact value, therefor it will use some guessing which sometimes goes wrong

Comment: Traditionally SQL Server cached a plan based on  the **first** set of values it gets for the parameters, @Sametcey . This is a *flawed* solution, but also expected and well documented, and a frequently discussed topic. This is why the feature I mention in my prior comment was introduced, to try and alleviate  the issue; it only, however, works with equality operators, and with `AND` constraints (not `OR`), so it's far from a complete fix, but it *is* a start.

Comment: btw, which jdbc driver are you using ?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3257/different-approaches-to-correct-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/